# Spring Mvc integration test fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I want to write an integration test for a delete method in my controller, but no matter how many times I tried rewriting it, I am still getting different errors.
This is the method in my controller:

```
@Controller
public class AgencyController {

    @Autowired
    private AgencyService agencyService;

    @Autowired
    private AgencyMapper agencyMapper;
@GetMapping("/deleteAgencyPage/{id}")
    public String deleteAgencyPage(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        agencyService.deleteById(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

And this is the test, plain and simple, only a call to the method and checking a status:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-h2.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser(username = "user1@gmail.com")
@ActiveProfiles("H2")
public class AgencyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    AgencyService agencyService;

    @MockBean
    AgencyMapper agencyMapper;

    @MockBean
    Model model;

 @Test
    public void deleteAgency() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/deleteAgencyPage/{id}",1L))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /deleteAgencyPage/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user1@gmail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.awbdproject.controllers.AgencyController
           Method = com.example.awbdproject.controllers.AgencyController#deleteAgencyPage(Long)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = redirect:/
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Language:"en", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Location:"/"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<302>
Expected :200
Actual   :302
```

What am I not doing correct? It seems a simple test to me, but I am obviously missing something.

Comment: In your test you are expecting a HTTP 200 status code although you are returning a `redirect:` in your controller which leads to a redirect, here HTTP 302. Just try returning `null` to see the difference.

Comment: Yes, it works that way, but I had other tests that returned views (not redirects, but direclty a view like `return "home"` and in those tests the status was indeed 200 and that's why I didn't get it when I came to this situation.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. A "home" return value serves your rendered template (HTTP 200), a HTTP 302 redirect is a response to the client (browser) telling that the resource has (temporarily) moved. This response almost only contains the new URL. A browser normally follows this new URL automatically, your test does not. For a better understanding, investigate the response headers using `curl -I` or the network tab of your browser.

Comment: I got it, it's really clearer now, thanks so much!!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have just summarized my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration test works correctly. For example, a "home" return value serves your rendered template with a HTTP 200 *Ok* status. Here, a redirect leads to a HTTP 302 *Found* status. This response tells the client (browser) that the resource has (temporarily) moved.

Changing the test to `.andExpect(status().isFound())` would make it succeed.